# Convergency test on a series with a factorial

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What convergence test can I apply to

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^2e^n}?$$

Using the ratio test, I found the ratio goes to infinity when $n \to \infty$, so the test was inconclusive.  No comparison test I could think of helped either. Any ideas?

Comment: "Series" is singular (as well as plural).  The word "serie" has no meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ratio of $a_{n+1}$ to $a_n$ tends to $\infty$  then ratio test shows that the series diverges.

The test is conclusive if the ratio tends to $\infty$. Proof: $a_{n+1} >2a_n$ for $n \geq $ some $m$. So $a_{m+k} \geq 2^{k} a_m$ for all $k$ and so $a_n$ does not even tend to $0$. A series $\sum a_n$ cannot converges  unless $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: I thought the ratio test was inconclusive if the limit of the ratio was $1$ or didn't exist. I thought this "didn't exist" refered to infinity, or minus infinity.

Comment: I have added an explanation. @lafinur